# QGIS 2.0 Can I get panels to display as tabs

Tags: qgis

I recently got myself very confused by getting the "Layers" panel hidden under the "Layer order" panel and then spent hours wondering why I could no longer right click on the layer to get the menu.

I like to have the option of floating or tabbed displays for panels.

Is this possible?  I have searched the manuals and gone through the setting but I may well have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dock panels have three different states.

**Floating**

Just click and drag the panel header until it floats.

[image]

**Docked Stacked**

Just click and drag the panel header until it floats. Drag the panel until it snaps under the other panel.

[image]

**Docked Tabbed**

Just click and drag the panel header. Drag the panel until the other one is highlighted

[image]

Comment: thanks Nathan.  I have got stacking to work but still can not get them into tabbed state. I can not get the other to highlight when I drag a panel.  At least this solves my basic problem of inadvertently 'loosing' panels!